# How can I use my saved volume data after restarting docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab, teamcity

I have a Docker container based on Linux on a PC running Windows. I have pulled and installed Gitlab CI/CD. Everything is running and I log in to Gitlab, but every time I restart the docker container it is like I lose all my data. I understand it overrides the previous data, saved inside the container, but I need a way to "persist" that data. From my understanding the only way is to point the volumes of the Gitlab image to directories saved on my PC somehow. How do I do this or something similar to this so I won't lose my data on Docker restart?

The script I ran to instantiate gitlab image is the following:

```
docker run -d --hostname gitlab.wproject.gr \
-p 4433:443 -p 80:80 -p 2223:22 \
--name gitlab-server1 \
--restart always \
--volume /storage/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
--volume /storage/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
--volume /storage/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put relative links for your volumes instead of absolute links. If you use Docker Desktop on Windows the volume management doesn't always behave the same way as on Linux.

Test with:

```sh
mkdir gitlab

docker run -d --hostname gitlab.wproject.gr \
-p 4433:443 -p 80:80 -p 2223:22 \
--name gitlab-server1 \
--restart always \
--volume ./gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
--volume ./gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
--volume ./gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Apparently, this doesn't seem to work. To begin with, you cannot write relative path this way. It does not recognize the dot sign (.) and except that as I said when docker initializes, it resets these folders to the initial state of the image. What I need is to pass into initialization something that points out the existing data as initial data.